# WCF service parser error, unable to import binding 'xxx' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have a WCF service I am trying to run in IIS on my server. However, I have no idea what to do about this error, every fix I found from searching google didnt work. What am I missing here?

Error Message: Unable to import binding '...' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="MyService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyServiceBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" contract="MyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="https://IPADDRESS:443"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFWsHttpBindingHttps.MyServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

 <applicationSettings>
  <MyService.Properties.Settings>
   <setting name="MyService_MyOtherService_MyOtherService" serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://path-to-service/MyOtherService.svc</value>
   </setting>
  </MyService.Properties.Settings>
 </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

[edit] I should note that I get an error when hosting the service from IIS, on a DIFFERENT service that I have referenced. It hits line 1 of the WSDL and throws the parse error.

Comment: Have you properly installed WCF? Or have you implemented a custom binding? We could do with a bit more detail if you have it.

Comment: There is my web config, hopefuilly that gives you some insight. I believe WCF is properly installed. Is there a way to check if it isnt?

Comment: When do you get the error message?

Comment: check my edit, describes when i get it.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your web.config

- The service name and contract are the same which, although possible, is not best practice
- The service name should be fully qualified (namespaces included)
- The service behavior you have defined is not being referenced by your service element ( should add `behaviorConfiguration="WCFWsHttpBindingHttps.MyServiceBehavior"`)
- You should set `serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"` so that you can get proper error messages returned.

Comment: Well I copied from a previous post, so my names are actually fully qualified. My contract isnt named the same, that was a typo, but thaks for pointing out. I changed the other things also, but the includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" didnt add any new information to it.